# WKWebView for Subframes

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I am trying to use WKWebView to create a mobile web browser for a website.

The main problem with the website is it's made up of one main frame (login page) then a bunch of subframes.  I'm trying to use a WKNavigationDelegate to track each page that opens, but it only works on the main frame and can't track the subframes.

Is there a way around this issue, or a different tool I should be using?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi - what are you trying to accomplish with these frames? Are you just wanting to be alerted when a frame opens, or evalutate javascript, or...?

Comment: When navigating from one subframe to another, the screen format doesn't reload (ex: if you zoom in on one page, it will stayed zoomed when you go to a new page).  I'm looking to detect every time a new subframe loads so I can reformat the screen.

Comment: I see. So was @Asleepace's answer sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at implementing this method:

```
optional func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, 
      decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, 
      decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)
```

The `navigationAction` has a property `isMainFrame` that specifies if the current request is on the main frame, or a subframe.

You can read more [about it here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455641-webview).